# How to set the Navigation Drawer below the toolbar in Android?

Tags: java, android, material-design, navigation-drawer

How can I put my `ListView` below the toolbar?

Here is what I have now:

[image: ListView overlapping toolbar]

What I want to achieve is something like this:

[image: ListView below toolbar]

Comment: you should show your code, otherwise it's hard to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell for sure if I don't see your xml file. But try adding this to the layout you are using as a drawer.

```
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
```

Hope it helps.